# How to split screen from the center in iphone?

Tags: iphone, alarm

**I wanna split the screen from the center of my view like the application of "Best Alarm Clock" infoSpider,Inc**

[check the link of this application and in opening of application how it split from the center]

> http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/best-alarm-clock-free/id353404769?mt=8

Let me know how can i implement this feature in my application.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do it. The simple one, you can create an uiview an attached to your view controller.

**EDIT:**

Or you might want to use `UISplitViewController`

Comment: Which function of UISplitViewController should i use for iphone4?
Because UISplitViewController mostly used for ipad.